# includes not working easyphpdev server

Tags: php, php-include, devserver

I am running easyPHP Devserver 16.1.1 and having a bit of trouble with this local server, it won't show me any PHP locally.  I've tried reinstalling it but that doesn't help.

The program runs just fine, shows all the HTML I've got in the site but it does not process code like this:

```
<?php include("/menu.php"); ?>

<?php include("/slide1.php"); ?>
```

I am new too PHP and this is really hurting my stride..
Any ideas on how to fix this? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

if you are try to get file within same folder then you don't need to write like this

you can just write this

or 
include 'filename';

or

require 'filename';

for innner folder user folder path like this
require 'abc/b/filename';

Comment: This answer makes zero sense.